# How to deploy an A0 Linux VM in East US?

Tags: linux, azure

I've just signed up for Azure and am on a trial account. I want to perform perhaps one of the most basic operations - I want to create an A0 Linux VM in East US, but I find I'm unable to do so.

I'm using Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS as the image.

I've found if I select the "Resource Manager" deployment model, I can select East US for the region, but there are no A-class machine options (the most modest host is F1S). And if I select the "Classic" deployment model, I'm unable to select East US ("subscription doesn't allow machine creation in East US"). I can select US South Central and then the A0 provisioning is available.

How can I provision an A0 machine in East US? Why am I able to provision one using the classic deployment model? Why does the deployment model affect which regions to which I can deploy?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an Azure service-specific question that can't be answered here. Your best option is to open a billing support ticket (which is free to do), and request access to specific resources within the desired region.

Comment: There are many other regions (including East 2) - have you checked to see if you have access to A-series in any other region? Also, since you're just testing, is there a reason your services must be in East? (I highly doubt you'd see any perf difference between east and, say, central or west).

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered the answer. When using the "Resource Manager" deployment model, the UI prompts for the storage type (SSD or HDD) and SSD is the default. If SSD is selected, the lower tier hosts are unavailable. If on the other hand the Classic deployment model is used, the storage type is selected later, after selecting the host config. I suspect the reason that East US could not be selected was because East US no longer allows Classic deployments (not that the subscription didn't allow it).

Comment: So... FYI the A series VMs don't have any 'S' versions (like the DS or GS). And only the <something>S SKU's support SSD-based OS and attached data disks. It's not that you can't select a lower tier (that is, if there were, say, an AS version, that would be available). It's just that you can only select VMs supporting Premium storage.